# Why a reference declared of type Subclass can not refer to an Object of Super class?

Tags: java

Hello am unable to understand why subclass variable cannot reference superclass object as per below code.

```
class Superclass{
}

class Subclass extends Superclass{  
}

public class DemoClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Superclass obj = new Subclass();   //Valid
        Subclass obj2 = new Superclass();  //Invalid

    }

}
```

Comment: Developer writing the code for Parent does not know what additional behavior the developer of Child class will put in Child class. If any such method is invoked then object of Parent class will have no idea as how to perform that operation. You can invoke any operation based on the declaration typer of a reference.  Read my answer for more detailed explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44481873/504133

Answer (score 3):

Because the OOP doesn't work in this way. 
A variable with the type of the subclass cannot  reference an object of its super class :

```
Subclass obj2 = new Superclass();
```

As any instance of a super class is not necessary an instance of a specific subclass.

But the reverse is possible :

```
Superclass obj = new Subclass();
```

As any subclass instance is finally an instance of the super class.

To understand, why you cannot do the first assignment ( assigning a parent instance to a variable declared with the subclass type), suppose this code worked :

```
Animal animal = new Dog(); 
Cat cat = animal; // should not be legal
```

You  assigned a `Dog` to a `Cat` variable as the `animal` variable refers to a `Dog` instance. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

An instance of `Subclass` is always also an instance of `Superclass`, so you can assign

```
Superclass obj = new Subclass();
```

On the other hand, not all instances of `Superclass` are instances of `Subclass`, so you cannot assign a `Superclass` instance to a `Subclass` variable.

Some instances of `Superclass` are also instances of `Subclass`, so you can cast a `Superclass` instance to a `Subclass` in order to make the assignment:

```
    Superclass obj = new Subclass();
    Subclass obj2 = (Subclass) obj;
```

However, but in your example (`Subclass obj2 = new Superclass();`) you are trying to assign an instance that is **not** a `Subclass` to a `Subclass` variable, so even with casting cannot work.

Comment: And is the explanation of Animal,Cat and Dog classes given by user davidxxx below satisfy what you have explained..?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a subclass object and treat it "generically" as a superclass object, but you can't have a generic superclass object and treat it as a more specific subclass object because it isn't a subclass object.
Suppose that in your subclass there is a method, let's call it foo(), that doesn't exists in your superclass: if you were allowed to store a superclass object in a subclass type, how would the compiler understand that you can't use the method foo() on that object?

```
public class Superclass {

}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    void foo() {
        //...
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String...s) {
        Subclass obj = new SuperClass();
        obj.foo(); //THIS
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this might help you understand. I will try to answer this question with simple english instead of code.

The actual difference here is that the **SubClass, is meant to be a more specialised version of the SuperClass**. Technically it should be able to **do something more**, or **store some extra properties**.

On that note, if you try to describe the SubClass as a SuperClass then this no longer holds true, because a SuperClass will NOT be able to serve the same purpose. Functions will be missing from the SuperClass and well as properties.

Therefore, if it was possible for a SubClass to be described as a SuperClass, in practice it would not be a SubClass anymore. It would be like overwriting the contract of the object type on the fly, which violates the constraints of the language.

On the contrary, a SubClass holds all the functionality and properties of the SuperClass, so it can act as a SubClass as well as a SuperClass (except if you explicitly override functionality). That's a property originating from Inheritance.

In your example SubClass and SuperClass have no real difference. In such a case, there is no practical way of having a SubClass. Possibly it could be related with a design decision if you plan to extend the functionality in the future and you want to differentiate the two. But even if they are identical, you need to understand that by using the extend keyword, it is like saying "Hey, there is something more in this class" and this comes with the constraints discussed previously.

Answer (score 1):

When you inherit from a class, you always specialize the common behavior of the super class.

In your example, the `Subclass` is a special `Superclass`. It inherits all behavior from the super class and can override behavior to make it different or add new behavior.

It's not allowed because **subclasses** generally define additional behavior. If you could assign a superclass object to a subclass reference, you would run into problems at runtime when you try to access class members that don't actually exist.

There are two approaches to refer a subclass object. Both have some advantages/disadvantages over the other:

1. **First approach (Referencing using Superclass reference)**: A reference variable of a superclass can be used to a refer any subclass object derived from that superclass. If the methods are present in SuperClass, but overridden by SubClass, it will be the overridden method that will be executed.
2. **Second approach (Referencing using subclass reference)**: A subclass reference can be used to refer its object.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
           // using superclass reference
           // first approach
            Superclass sub1 = new Subclass();

           // using subclass reference( )
           // second approach
           Subclass sub2 = new Subclass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sub classes are extension to the base class**. *Base classes do not know and can not behave like Sub class*

```
Parent p = new Child() // Child knows and behaves like parent and can override some behavior too

Child c = new Parent() // author of Parent class has no idea as how Child will be implemented 
  // and what extra behaviors will be added in child. 
 // If any behavior of parent is invoked on c, the object of Parent class will not know how to perform it.
```

Its simple to understand, Lets take an example closer to real world.

1. Apple, Mango and Kiwi are fruits. If we represent them as java classes we can say Apple, Mango and Kiwi classes, all extends from  Fruit class.
2. For a code declaring something like `ClassA obj = new ....` lets for time being ignore the `...` and see `ClassA`, its the declared type for reference `obj`. Now all the public methids which are there in `ClassA` can be invoked on `obj`.
3. Suppose `Fruit.java` has a method `public String getTaste()` which returns `sweet`. All the sub classes inherits `getTaste` method from their super class. `getTaste` can be invoked on all of : Mango, Kiwo, Apple.
4. Suppose `Mango.java` developer decides to add an additional method in it called `convertToMangoShake()`.
5. Note that its just the mango which can get ready for  converting to a mango shake.

   Any fruit other than Mango can not get ready to be converted to mango shake. Apple, and Kiwi can not get ready for converting to mango shake. Any such action to ask kiwo to get ready to convert to mango shake will be an **Error**
6. Now if you say `Mango mango = new Fruit()` and now as the method `convertToMangoShake()` is invoked like `mango.convertToMangoShake()` , an error will be thrown as Fruit does not know this method.